# Crashplan Destination Unavailable

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, crashplan

I'm using the free version of CrashPlan on Win7 to backup two computers at home.
The main one has a 2TB external hard drive, which is set as a backup destination.
I have another laptop, on the same CrashPlan account, which is also set to backup to the main computer.

I have few similar issues:

- On the main computer (connected with USB to the external hard drive) I have many cases that I see CrashPlan say it has not ran a backup for a few days since the "Destination is unavailable". When I try to access the hard drive I can see it is working fine, and when I click the "Backup now" button it will suddenly find it and start the backup process
- On the laptop (this might be related to the first problem) I had issues connecting to the remote backup destination (the main computer), and I got the same "Destination Unavailable" message. I read some FAQs and opened a firewall port on the laptop which got it to work and complete a full backup. Ever since that full backup, it is showing again the "Destination Unavailable" message and won't do any more backups.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's to do with either the main computer or the USB hard drive going to sleep and the backup not being able to wake up the device? What are the power settings on the two PCs? You could try changing them so that they don't sleep at all for a few days to see if that helps. Might not be a long term solution but at least it might point to the problem

Comment: The main computer never sleeps. The hard drive doesn't go to sleep as far as I can tell.
The laptop I'm trying to back up remotely is on for most of the day.

Comment: OK. Anything in the log files? http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/Reading_CrashPlan_App_Log_Files

Comment: Is it possible that the drive letter of the external drive has changed (even temporarily)? I also found via google many user complaints for the same error, but no convincing answer from CrashPlan.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to open CrashPlan, double-click on the green house icon in the top right corner of that window, then enter 'restart' as a command. I then closed the command window and the whole program disappeared. I waited for it to restart but it didn't visibly do so. Then I opened it manually and it was working fine.

Hope this might help!

Comment: I used this method multiple times, on both machines, with no success. Also tried restarting the machine

Comment: Sorry it didn't help, that's unfortunately all I've got because it worked for me! Hope you manage to sort it

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case this procedure really helped.

Answer (score 2):

I know this won't solve your problem with CrashPlan but I had the same issue as you. CrashPlan was always telling me that that backup was unavailable for some obscure reason. Apparently maintenance of the files.
The thing is it hadn't back up anything for the last 28 days.

I decided to give a go to [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/) and so far it seems to be working smoothly.
Duplicati is totally free (and won't annoy you with ads as a nice bonus).

Answer (score 0):

Open Crashplan at destination computer. Look at Inbound section in the upper right corner. click arrow and choose attach archive.  Select the archive file from the source computer. Should work after this.

Also have worked for me is install an up to date version of Crashplan.  Or reinstall Crashplan.